# Fetch only first row from a result set in Snowflake stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a stored procedure in a snowflake that has to join 3 tables and output the first row in `JSON` format.

Is there a way to fetch only the first row??

Currently I am iterating the result set and breaking the loop after the first iteration.

```
   while(result.next()){
      id = result.getColumnValue(1);
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Could you just add `LIMIT 1` to the SQL statement so that only 1 record is returned to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

If you just call resultSet.next(); on its own (not in a WHILE statement) then it will make the first record in the resultset available e.g.

```
var resultSet = stmt.execute();
resultSet.next();
var my_sfDate = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
```

Obviously, if you need a specific record (not just a random first record) you would need an ORDER BY clause in the statement you are executing

Comment: I get this error   ResultSet is empty or not prepared (call next() first)

Comment: You have, I assume, integrated my code snippet into your SP and changed it as necessary? "stmt" obviously needs to match the SQL statement you've prepared in your code

Comment: I have the same variable name.

Comment: I think you'd need to update your question with the full code you are running (or at least the section where you prepare and execute the SQL and then read the result) in order for me to help further